# react.js hook (too many re-renders)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm new to react.js hook. Not sure about why the following code doesn't work.

```
import React,{useEffect,useState} from "react"

function App() {

  const [fruit,setFruit] = useState("orange");
  setFruit("apple")      
  
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{fruit}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The error says that

```
Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting the state inside the functional component body (The `setFruit("apple")` line) which will cause the component to re-render and when this happens all the component body will rerun again which will cause another set state call and so on which ultimately causes an infinite loop.

If you want to set the state when the component is mounting, You can use the `useEffect` hook to achieve that like so:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setFruit("apple")
}, []);
```

Read more about the hook [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I know the circumstance that cause re-rendering is when the state is changed, but after the change from "orange" to "apple", setFruit("apple") doesn't make the state changed right? I mean "apple" is still "apple".

Comment: When you call setFruit regardless of what you're passing it will always update the previous value with whatever you passed. What you're talking about will matter in the useEffect hook if the fruit changed from 'orange' to 'apple' the effect body will be executed only once upon changing, I created a little demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-poincare-l0de3?file=/src/App.js) for you open the console and click on the button as much as you want :)

Comment: Thank you so much! I learned a lot in this post ! I think I fully understand! Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

you need to use useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
 setFruit("apple") 
}, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

The actual pattren of react is that when you set a state it cause rerender that means component re run again and recompile every line of code if it found a set state fucntion again it rerender and that's what happening in youe code. To prevent this you can use useEffect hook which accepts a callback function and a dependency array

**For Example**

```
useEffect(() => {}, []);
```

The code in every useEffect will run with first time component mount and if you want to run the code again you need to pass dependency in 2nd argument of useEffect which decide that if the dependency change it's value the code in useEffect will run again.

In your case you can set state like this

```
useEffect(() => {
   setFruit("apple")
}, []);
```